# How to catch proxy response and redirect using http-proxy-middleware?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, http-proxy-middleware

I have webpack-dev-server serving static files. (localhost:4000)
I have backend server serving api request. (localhost)

Before that, there is a authentication with idp provider.

when I visit `localhost:4000`, it gets proxied into `localhost` for authentication.

`localhost` server redirects to idp for authentication, once authenticated idP redirects back to 'localhost'. Now this is the problem. I want it to be redirected to `localhost:4000` not `localhost`.

Is there anyway to achieve this?